# My switch statement doesn't give the expected result

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```
let a = prompt('No?')

switch (a) {
    case 1:
        console.log('Answer 1')
        break
    case 2:
        console.log('Answer 2')
        break
}
```

I am writing this in chrome's JavaScript console and it just returns 'undefined' instead of printing the statements.
What have i done wrong?

Comment: prompt returns a string not a number, so either parse it or change cases to strings

Comment: Understood thanks.
:)

Answer (score 2):

Krzysztof's solution with example code.

**Method 1 (change cases to strings):**

```js
let a = prompt('No?')

switch (a) {
    case '1':
        console.log('Answer 1')
        break
    case '2':
        console.log('Answer 2')
        break
    default:
        console.log('Incorrect No')
        break
}
```

**Method 2 (parsing to int):**

```js
let a = prompt('No?')

switch (parseInt(a,10)) {
    case 1:
        console.log('Answer 1')
        break
    case 2:
        console.log('Answer 2')
        break
    default:
        console.log('Incorrect No')
        break
}
```

Comment: Why no `default`?